# Catch click on select, add options, then open the select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, ecmascript-5

I've been trying to "catch" the click event on a select element, then add `<option>` fields dynamically based on some other Elements in the DOM, and then fire an event to open the dropdown of the select element.

I sucessfully managed to catch the click event and add `<option>` fields. I'm having trouble opening the select with my current approach tho. What I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("mousedown", "#select-box", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var options = "";
        $(".some-div").each(function(i, obj){
            var id = $(obj).attr("id");
            options += '<option value="' + id + '">' + id + '</option>';
        });
        
        $("#select-box").html(options);
        
        // - Open the select dropdown here -
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="some-div" id="div1">
<div class="some-div" id="div2">
<div class="some-div" id="div3">

<select id="select-box">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Div</option>
</select>
```

So if you run that snippet, click the select and inspect it in DevTools, it does have the dynamic options I need. But I don't know how to actually open it. Some answers here on StackOverflow suggested firing the `mousedown` event manually by using

```js
$("#select-box").trigger("mousedown");
```

but that obviously doesn't work, because that's the very event I'm catching right from the start.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to trigger the default behavior, so remove

```
e.preventDefault();
```

I think it's also stopping your code from functioning the way you think (?). I'm not seeing 3 IDs get added to the dropdown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For me the ID's are added just they way they are supposed to. See [here](https://imgur.com/a/EjhZtZK). Removing the `e.preventDefault()` seems to work on Chrome. But is that method safe? Like, isn't it possible that the dropdown is opened BEFORE the `<option>` fields are added?

Comment: Busted. I admit I didn't check dev tools to see if they are all added. I don't think removing preventDefault will ever *cause* a dropdown because dropping the list is an event that must be triggered by something. It's like stopping the bell from ringing when you press the doorbell - stopping the bell won't cause someone to ring the bell. The one thing I've been trying to confirm is that the dropping of the list is actually the default event. I'm having a hard time finding a definitive list of default events.

Comment: Despite your comment, removing the `e.preventDefault()` does seem to work. [See the demo here](https://jsbin.com/kibidoxapa/edit?html,js,output). I just don't know if the elements are >always< added before the dropdown is opened. If that's not the case, then this isn't really an answer to my question

Comment: Um, what do you mean, despite my comment? The problem has nothing to do with whether the elements are added - they are added. The problem is the preventDefault and removing it is the fix.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just having a hard time understanding the exact sequence of events that occur. User clicks on the select element -> My function catches that event (mousedown) -> performs the operations within my function and AFTER that function exited, the browser renders the actual drop down menu? I just want to make sure, that the dropdown isn't rendered simultaneously with the execution of my function which could cause a race condition, e.g. rendering the dropdown BEFORE my function added all the elements.

Comment: I think I know what you're saying. My bet is that the function has to finish first, otherwise the page will literally not know what to render. It's the same way that a page will actually stop rendering when it is loaded. If the page comes across a javascript file, the rendering stops and the js file must be read and acted on because the js can alter the page, so there's no reason to finish rendering without knowing *what* to render. (I can't guarantee that's what happens here but that's my best guess.) Hth.

Comment: Yep! Just tested it. It seems like the function has to return anything but false in order for the dropdown to be rendered. That means the function body is always executed before the dropdown is rendered. I tried manually returning false at the end of my function, and just as I thought, the dropdown didn't show up. So your answer solved my problem. Thank you very much! :)